# PHP Show Page If Cookies Are Set

Tags: php, cookies

**Current Code**

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "testr";
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        header("Location: http://admin.rafflebananza.com/authenticate.php");
        exit;
        } else { ?>

<!-- HTML PAGE GOES HERE -->

<?php } ?>
```

My current code looks like the above, but I've got a feeling this is not the way to do things as Dreamweaver says there is an error doing it this way.

What is the best way to redirect if the cookies have not been set before loading the page

Comment: That should work. Dreamweaver may be confused by the open `{` followed by raw HTML.  But the logic works in PHP.

Comment: Have a look at sessions in php, that's not the way you will want to check if a user is authenticated, if that's what you try to do.

Comment: That said, you _don't need_ the `else` because if you have not already redirected away, the remaining code would be executed and the HTML displayed. So you can just get rid of the `else { }` and place your HTML after the closing of the `if (...) { }`

Comment: @Marius.C I'm not checking a user session, I need to implement that as well, this is to see if they've run the set up wizard for the admin panel prefs and accepting our cookies

Comment: Brilliant @MichaelBerkowski, I never thought of that!

Comment: @TimMarshall do you want it as an answer?

Comment: @TimMarshall whatever you do, is not safe. I can create whatever cookie I want in my browser for whatever domain, so what you try to do there can be bypassed easily

Comment: @Marius.C Yes you could, however this is for the time being and I'll have a login system implemented and to check session and whatnot.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Why not, it works :)

Comment: One could easily add a cookie for `testr` and  circumvent any authentication you have in place.  This is NOT how you handle authentication.

Comment: authentication is NOT what I am doing @MikeBrant what I am doing is bringing up their theme preferences, if not redirecting to set their preferences

Comment: @TimMarshall Ahh.  The script you were redirecting to is shown as `authenticate.php` thus the reason for my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how Dreamweaver lints PHP code these days, but have often seen false positives on Stack Overflow where Dreamweaver reports syntax errors erroneously.  The code and logic you have now is valid, if a little ugly.

Since the `if()` condition's action is to redirect away and explicitly `exit`, you actually have no need for the `else {}` block. You can directly follow the `if () {}` with the HTML content and PHP will output it because it has not already redirected away and terminated execution.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "testr";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    header("Location: http://example.com/authenticate.php");
    exit;
}
// No else {} block
// Follow this directly with your HTML    
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>everything else...</body>
</html>
```

As has been pointed out in the comment thread, using a cookie alone as a guard for authentication is insufficient and not secure, unless the cookie's value can be validated with a secret in the code, like a one-time-use token. In that case, it may be more appropriate to store a value in `$_SESSION` which cannot be modified by the client browser.